# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: + at com.google.android.gms.internal.dv.u(Unknown Source)

Tags: android, admob

My app users are reporting following error for the last 2 weeks.

I could not reproduce it on simulator as well as real device. Is it a problem with google play services?

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: + 
at com.google.android.gms.internal.dv.u(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.as.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
at org.chittu.gold.activities.BaseActivity.requestAd(BaseActivity.java:77)
at org.chittu.gold.activities.IndianGoldPricesActivity.onCreate(IndianGoldPricesActivity.java:162)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5350)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2344)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5294)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can u add your code ?

Comment: Did you add the proguard config for google play services?